# What is the difference between Xamarin built-in Hot-reload and something like Live Xaml

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-emulator, visual-studio-emulator

I recently started working on xamarin form app.
In Xamarin there is Host reload which reloads the Design when running (in debug run ).
Then there is Live Xaml which paid so what is the difference between the both of them?

Answer (score 1):

Both use the same technique to achieve the same result. It took some time for Xamarin to come up with Hot Reload, so there were some others that came up with this solution. One of which was Live XAML.

I'm not entirely up to date about the features on both, one might have something over the other. But the main difference is: one is developed by Microsoft and supplied with all the other tooling, the other is from a third-party.

Up to you to decide which one you'll use and why.

Comment: Also, HotReload still doesn't support UWP (for XForms), while livexaml does.

Comment: So As my app is only on Android so there is nothing extra I can get by paying for Live Xaml .
I was thinking that LiveXaml can do something like getting the style from another page which is need a restart in Hot reload